# vimのVundleでninjaのsyntax fileをインストールする

Tags: vim

vimのVundleを使ってninja-buildのsyntax fileをインストールしたいのですが、どうすればいいのでしょうか?

Vundleではgithubのリポジトリ自体がプラグインになっていたり、vim.org上のプラグインは簡単にインストールできます。

しかし、ninjaのsyntax fileのように1つのファイルのみのプラグインのインストールはどうすればよいのでしょうか?

ninjaのsyntax fileは下記リンク先にあります
https://github.com/ninja-build/ninja/blob/master/misc/ninja.vim

Vundleを使わずに`rtp`に追加することはできますが、極力Vundleで管理したいと思っています

Answer (score 1):

ninja-build repository を Vundle でインストールした後、`$HOME/.vim/syntax/` ディレクトリに `ninja.vim` へのシンボリックリンクファイルを作成するというのはいかがでしょうか(予め `$HOME/.vim/syntax/` ディレクトリを作成しておきます)。

**$HOME/.vimrc**

```
Bundle 'ninja-build/ninja'
silent execute '! [ -f ~/.vim/syntax/ninja.vim ] || ln -sf ~/.vim/bundle/ninja/misc/ninja.vim ~/.vim/syntax/'
```